# How to create a Windows-mountable ISO file with mkisofs/genisoimage?

Tags: linux, windows, iso-image

I'm attempting to create Windows-compatible ISO files from a Python script running on Linux. I cannot seem to find the appropriate flags for mksisofs to enable Windows to read the file (attempting to mount the file in Windows results in "Sorry, there was a problem mounting the file."). I've attempted many variations of including -J, -udf, -R, -HFS, -iso-level, and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not trying to mount the ISO file over a UNC path, a lot of different options will work. In case anyone else might run into this: Windows won't let you mount an ISO file over UNC path (or has other requirements for allowing that).